# `Error $ is invalid for atomic vectors` when replacing columns in a dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace a column in my dataset in RStudio so I used this code:

```
weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(x$Y))
```

but I keep getting an error message saying `Error in x$Y: $ is invalid for atomic vectors`. Please how do I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: It would help if you could share a data sample as code, e.g. by running `dput(head(x))` and pasting the output into the body of your question. I suspect `x` is a vector but you are using notation as if it were a list or a data frame (technically a special kind of list) with an element within it named `Y`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An ***atomic vector*** is a simple vector of one of the basic vector types: "logical, integer, real, complex, string (or character) and raw".<sup>1</sup> An atomic vector can have multiple values, but always of the same type. Data frame columns are an example of atomic vectors.

A ***list*** (a.k.a. *generic vector*) is a different data type; it can hold multiple vectors of different types. Examples of lists are `list`, `data.frame`, `data.table`, etc.

The ***$*** is an operator to take a subset of a list.<sup>2</sup> It can only be used on lists, not on atomic vectors.

Basically, R is complaining that `x$Y` is invalid, that x is an atomic type, and as such the $ operator has no meaning on it.

You say you are trying to replace a column in your "data set"; I'm assuming you have a data frame, with a column of character strings that represent dates. However, `x` is apparently not the name of that data frame.

1. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Vector-objects
2. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Operators